# Как работать с cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

```js
fetch('localhost:5000/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify('awawdawd')
});
```

Делаю fetch-запрос на сервер, но получаю предупреждение о cors. Как можно обработать POST-запрос на сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С серверной стороны как правило достаточно установить пакет `cors` и сделать так:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
```

Если нужны продвинутые настройки CORS, см. описание пакета [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Я знаю, что так можно сделать. Но мне нужно для конкретного домена

Comment: var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}

Comment: @Voprositel вам же скинули ссылку, где есть вся информация, об этом там тоже говорится

Comment: @Inventor, я не заметил